# Exception prob while installing sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

How to solve windows.componentmodel.win32 Exception

this exception occured during sharepoint installing

please any one give me the sollution

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter all the usernames in the format DOMAIN\USERNAME